# Extracting a substring using a specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I need to extract some data that I'm receiving from another process.
The received content varies quite a bit in length and format but there is one piece of information that I need that is always in the same format.

Example 1:

```
This is the first example (with a lot of content that I don't need) but the important piece of info is this: (test1 / jibberish)
```

Example 2:

```
This is another example (test2 / something I'm not interested in)
```

The only information I'm interested in is a string which always has the same pattern

> (info / some code)

It's only the "info"-bit I'm interested in.
So is there something (like Regex?) I can use to extract a temporary string (maybe even without parentheses) that I can then perform a substring on using the / ?

So the output becomes

```
info
```

Thanks

Comment: You answered your own question: you can do this with Regex. So read up on that, plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Read up on regex... I don't have 2 years....

Comment: @Cainnech regex is not so complicated, you don't need 2 years, for your example, something like this would be work: `\(([\w\s']+) \/ ([\w\s']+)\)`

Comment: Thank you thibsc. So in the above case the w+ means the content is ignored? Also, do I need to add a ^ in the beginning and an $ at the end? So:  \^((\w+) \/ (\w+)\)$ ?

Comment: No because we don't want to check the all string but just find the part that interest you which is: a `parenthesis \(` followed by `any word character or space or quote [\w\s']+` followed by `space`, then `slash`, then again the same thing and closed `parenthesis`.
The parenthesis around `[\w\s']+` is to specify what do you want to capture

Comment: Ok i think I get it, more or less. Thank you for your help

Comment: In c# you can use [lookarounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#grouping-constructs) to simplify your regex and only match what you actually want: for example `(?<=\()\w+(?= \/)` demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tKIhS8/2)

Answer (score 0):

in notepad++ i would do 
Find :- `\((.+?)\/.+`
replace:- `\1`